# GoogleMaps IOS SDK: viewMap.myLocationEnabled = true. not working

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I'm trying to get the first view is the current position of the user on the map but I always dies app on line 22. Thank you very much to anyone who can help me or maybe some other way to do this

```
viewMap.myLocationEnabled = true
```

Throws this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setMyLocationEnabled:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14c5bde10'
```

for the following code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps

class WhereViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var viewMap: GMSMapView!
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var didFindMyLocation = false



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        viewMap.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
        print("despues de observer")
        viewMap.myLocationEnabled = true // Line 22
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.AuthorizedWhenInUse{
            viewMap.myLocationEnabled = true
            print("sali de locationManager")
        }
    }

    override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if !didFindMyLocation{
            print("dentro de observer false")
            let myLocation: CLLocation = change![NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as! CLLocation
            viewMap.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(myLocation.coordinate, zoom: 10.0)
            viewMap.settings.myLocationButton = true

            didFindMyLocation = true
        }
        print("dentro de observer false")
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the class type of your view to GMSMapView in Interface Builder (set your view's Custom Class in Identity Inspector). Currently it is UIView, and you are sending it the message setMyLocationEnabled: that cannot be recognized.

Comment: I return to my home and I'll try. Thank you very much